# Does convertFromHTML support custom block types in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

[Here's a codepen example of the issue.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRRYrX?editors=0010)

I have added a custom block type called `section`, which wraps up selected text in red. It works fine when you click on the `section` in the edit toolbar. However, when used with `convertFromHTML` to render initial content,

`const sampleMarkup =
  '<b>Bold text</b><br/>Section Testing:<section>dsasdasad</section><br/><i>Italic text</i>';`

the editor is still treating `section` type as `unstyle` type. Does `convertFromHTML` support custom block types for initial rendering? Is there a solution for this?

Code:

```
      const {Editor,convertFromHTML,ContentState, EditorState,DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap, RichUtils} = Draft;

      const blockRenderMap = Immutable.Map({
    'section': {
        element: 'section'
    }
});

     const extendedBlockRenderMap = DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap.merge(blockRenderMap);

      class RichEditorExample extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          const sampleMarkup =
  '<b>Bold text</b><br/>Section Testing:<section>dsasdasad</section><br/><i>Italic text</i>';

          const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
          const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
            blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
            blocksFromHTML.entityMap
          );

          this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state)};

          this.focus = () => this.refs.editor.focus();
          this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});

          this.handleKeyCommand = (command) => this._handleKeyCommand(command);
          this.onTab = (e) => this._onTab(e);
          this.toggleBlockType = (type) => this._toggleBlockType(type);
          this.toggleInlineStyle = (style) => this._toggleInlineStyle(style);
        }

        _handleKeyCommand(command) {
          const {editorState} = this.state;
          const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);
          if (newState) {
            this.onChange(newState);
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }

        _onTab(e) {
          const maxDepth = 4;
          this.onChange(RichUtils.onTab(e, this.state.editorState, maxDepth));
        }

        _toggleBlockType(blockType) {
          this.onChange(
            RichUtils.toggleBlockType(
              this.state.editorState,
              blockType
            )
          );
        }

        _toggleInlineStyle(inlineStyle) {
          this.onChange(
            RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
              this.state.editorState,
              inlineStyle
            )
          );
        }

        render() {
          const {editorState} = this.state;

          // If the user changes block type before entering any text, we can
          // either style the placeholder or hide it. Let's just hide it now.
          let className = 'RichEditor-editor';
          var contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
          if (!contentState.hasText()) {
            if (contentState.getBlockMap().first().getType() !== 'unstyled') {
              className += ' RichEditor-hidePlaceholder';
            }
          }

          return (
            <div className="RichEditor-root">
              <BlockStyleControls
                editorState={editorState}
                onToggle={this.toggleBlockType}
              />
              <InlineStyleControls
                editorState={editorState}
                onToggle={this.toggleInlineStyle}
              />
              <div className={className} onClick={this.focus}>
                <Editor
                  blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
                  blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
                  customStyleMap={styleMap}
                  editorState={editorState}
                  handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  onTab={this.onTab}
                  placeholder="Tell a story..."
                  ref="editor"
                  spellCheck={true}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      // Custom overrides for "code" style.
      const styleMap = {
        CODE: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
          fontFamily: '"Inconsolata", "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace',
          fontSize: 16,
          padding: 2,
        },
      };

      function getBlockStyle(block) {
        switch (block.getType()) {
          case 'blockquote': return 'RichEditor-blockquote';
          default: return null;
        }
      }

      class StyleButton extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.onToggle = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.onToggle(this.props.style);
          };
        }

        render() {
          let className = 'RichEditor-styleButton';
          if (this.props.active) {
            className += ' RichEditor-activeButton';
          }

          return (
            <span className={className} onMouseDown={this.onToggle}>
              {this.props.label}
            </span>
          );
        }
      }

      const BLOCK_TYPES = [
        {label: 'H1', style: 'header-one'},
        {label: 'H2', style: 'header-two'},
        {label: 'H3', style: 'header-three'},
        {label: 'H4', style: 'header-four'},
        {label: 'H5', style: 'header-five'},
        {label: 'H6', style: 'header-six'},
        {label: 'Blockquote', style: 'blockquote'},
        {label: 'UL', style: 'unordered-list-item'},
        {label: 'OL', style: 'ordered-list-item'},
        {label: 'Code Block', style: 'code-block'},
        {label:'section',style:'section'},

      ];

      const BlockStyleControls = (props) => {
        const {editorState} = props;
        const selection = editorState.getSelection();
        const blockType = editorState
          .getCurrentContent()
          .getBlockForKey(selection.getStartKey())
          .getType();

        return (
          <div className="RichEditor-controls">
            {BLOCK_TYPES.map((type) =>
              <StyleButton
                key={type.label}
                active={type.style === blockType}
                label={type.label}
                onToggle={props.onToggle}
                style={type.style}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      };

      var INLINE_STYLES = [
        {label: 'Bold', style: 'BOLD'},
        {label: 'Italic', style: 'ITALIC'},
        {label: 'Underline', style: 'UNDERLINE'},
        {label: 'Monospace', style: 'CODE'},
      ];

      const InlineStyleControls = (props) => {
        var currentStyle = props.editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle();
        return (
          <div className="RichEditor-controls">
            {INLINE_STYLES.map(type =>
              <StyleButton
                key={type.label}
                active={currentStyle.has(type.style)}
                label={type.label}
                onToggle={props.onToggle}
                style={type.style}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      };

      ReactDOM.render(
        <RichEditorExample />,
        document.getElementById('target')
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late but I found a solution for that [here](https://www.altcademy.com/questions/how-to-solve-draft-dot-js-convertfromhtml-combining-adjacent-paragraphs-tags-into-one-contentblock). I couldn't find a way to set it at the initial render but if you couldn't set it at all, you can use this.

Example:

```
// convertToHtml is a custom function which returns convertFromHTML(html)
let htmlTranscript = convertToHtml(paragraphsArray)

// important part
htmlTranscript.contentBlocks[0] = htmlTranscript.contentBlocks[0].set('type', 'myType')

const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
                        htmlTranscript.contentBlocks,
                        htmlTranscript.entityMap
                    )

this.setState({
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

It's not well documented, but you need to pass the same `blockRenderMap` that you passed to the `Editor`, to the third argument of the `convertFromHTML` function.